# How to change the default mapping rules of struts-rest-pulgin

Tags: rest, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm using struts2 + convention + rest to build my Web project. There are many jsp files in the content folder. So I want to classify them by folders. For example, I want to put `user.jsp`, `user-list.jsp` and `user-edit.jsp` in `\content\user` folder. And I must add `Namespace` annotation to `UserController`, as follow:

```
@Namespace("/user")
public class UserController
```

But if I do that, the url to access `user.jsp` changes to `localhost:8080\projectName\user\user`. I don't like so much `user` int the url.

So my question is, can I change the default mapping rule to access `user.jsp` by `localhost:8080\projectName\user`? If I can't change it, then how to manage so much jsp files in `\WEB-INF\content` folder?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats a user controller? Why not just use the parent package annotation?

Comment: Thanks @Quaternion, I followed your suggestion to see the document of annotations in convention-plugin, and find out `@ResultPath` annotation can help me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read carefully enough, I'd assumed that you were creating the \user folder to apply an interceptor stack... I don't use the rest plugin, just conventions and so structure would look like: /user/list.jsp, /user/edit.jsp... that is the folder makes the entity implicit. I might have /user/list-error.jsp and /user/list-input.jsp.

Comment: Oh those folders are under /WEB-INF/content/ of course. I know this is asking a bit but as mentioned I'm not really familiar with the rest plugin, can you explain what you like about it?

Comment: @Quaternion Well, I'm newbie to struts world. I'd like to use rest plugin just to make the url clean so far. I know convention plugin can satisfy me, but I just want to have a try to rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out that the `@ResultPath` annotation can solve my issue. So the code become as follows:

```
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content/user")
public class UserController
```

By doing this, I could access `WEB-INF/content/user/user.jsp` file by url `localhost:8080/projectName/user`.

I'm still wondering if there is any approach to change the default result path to the way of `/WEB-INF/content/{controllerNamePrefix}` at a single position, instead of adding annotation to each controller class.